# Why won't Enthir sell me anything?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing through yesterday and managed to approach Enthir at the mage's College in Winterhold. He told me he could sell me hard to get items, and sure enough he did. I bought several Daedra hearts from him (which he restocks at 2 every 48 hours), and went off to build myself some new armour. 
The problem is this. Due to a save/load glitch I lost a couple of hours work yesterday and need to do this again. This time though, Enthir won't offer to sell me anything at all. He just keeps telling me what I can't do while at the college. Does anyone know why he won\t sell me anything as he is the best way to get Daedra hears without waiting for them to be randomly dropped.

Comment: I like how you refer to playing Skyrim as "work" =)

Comment: Is this still an issue you experience? If yes, how far are you in the Thieves Guild questline? And does he also not sell when he's at the Frozen Hearth inn?

Answer (score 4):

Visit him in his room. He won't sell anything while "at the college", because he deals in stolen goods.

Comment: His room is in the college. That's why I can't get him to sell me stuff already.

Answer (score 1):

From [there](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Onmund%27s_Request#Bugs), it seems you cannot speak to him if the quest *The Staff of Magnus* is active.
Is this the case for you?

Comment: No I have completed this one on both playthroughs. The only thing I can think of is that the first time, I found him just outside the college and I could ask him about buying things. He then told me to speak to him in his room. On the second one, I can only find him in his room.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in the Hall of Attainment, you can buy the hearts. If you went to be the arch mage without talking to him first, you cannot buy anything from him.

Comment: I have only completed the first quest for the college so far,

Answer (score -1):

I was not the archmage yet, in the middle of the staff of magnus quest. He will not even discuss anything other than the rules outside his room. For some reason, once you are embroiled with the college in this quest, he won't sell outside of his room either.

However, once he enters his room a "can we do business?" option is unlocked. Follow this conversation line and he will sell.

If you became arch mage before talking to him, then from what I can see on the great internet you are going to have a lot of trouble getting him to sell.